# How to create files depending on operations of parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have to take the `$4` parameter, divide it equally by `$2` parameter (If it cant be divided equally, add spaces to fill last part) and put every part at the end of randomized files we just created with

```
dir=$3

mkdir -p -- "$dir" || exit 1

fname=$(shuf -n 1 "$1")

tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 255 >"$dir/$fname"
```

It looks like this:

`script.sh <word_src> <size_of_parts> <out_dir> <text_to_process>`.

The number of files created depends on how many divided parts of the `$4` by `$2`. Basically I need to equally hide part of `<test_to_process>` in randoms files which will be in `<out_dir>`. Also would it be easier to process files in the meantime so they can be sorted alphabetically in `<out_dir>`?

Example :
`script.sh <word_src> 3 <out_dir>  this will be divided` .There "this will be divided" will be equally seperated in parts of 3 characters "thi" "s w" "ill" " be" " di" "vid" "ed ". In this example I needed to add a space at the end of `ed`. I will then send each individual parts at the end of my randomized files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This routine should solve your string-splitting task.  Adapt to your needs:

```
$ cat go.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
str="This will be divided"
ptr=0
interval=3
while [[ $ptr -le ${#str} ]]; do
   printf "'%-3s'\n" "${str:$((ptr)):$((interval))}"
   ptr=$((ptr+interval))
done
```

In use:

```
$ ./go.sh
'Thi'
's w'
'ill'
' be'
' di'
'vid'
'ed '
```

This uses `bash`'s built in parameter expansion tooling for substring extraction.  Given a variable `foo`:

- `$foo` is replaced with the contents of `foo`
- `${#foo}` is replaced with the number of items in `foo`.  For an array, this is the number of assigned values; for a non-array, this is the length of the string represented by `$foo` (`foo=10; echo ${#foo}` yields `2`).
- `${foo:4:4}` is replaced with the contents of `foo`, starting at the fifth character (zero is the first index), for four characters.

The last of these is the key here:  We use our string, a pointer for how many characters we've printed so far, and a defined interval.

We combine this with formated strings:  `%-3s` will output a left-justified, space-padded string.  So if we provide only one or two characters, space padding is added to the right for us.

To write to files, you can simply change

```
   printf "'%-3s'\n" "${str:$((ptr)):$((interval))}"
```

to

```
   fname="$dir/$(shuf -n 1 "$1")"
   tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 255 > "$fname"
   printf "'%-3s'\n" "${str:$((ptr)):$((interval))}" >> "$fname"
```

Comment: How would I then send each part to different files created dynamically depending on how many part we managed to separate?

Comment: I'd have thought that would be pretty straight forward and didn't need to be explicitly replicated as the question was about string splitting.  Rather than printing the split strings to console, write them to files (`printf [...] > /path/to/file`).

Comment: And instead of path on would I create the randomized file like I did and use it since it needs to be a new one for every part? Should I subshell my command before the `>` ?

Comment: See recent edit.

Comment: Looks promising will try that when I get home!

Comment: It works good, only thing is that I would need to send parts in files alphabetically, say were sending the string "abcdefghi", "abc" would need to be in the file "animal" for exemple, then "def" would need to be in the file "recruit", finally "ghi" would be in file "train", etc. Would I need to create files outside of the `while` loop ?

Comment: Probably, yes.  You could populate an array with the filenames and either populate it sparsely or if not, divide the index by three when accessing the array.

Comment: How would that be randomized?

Comment: Generate list of files, seed the files, `shuf` the list into an array.  Or, as my demonstrative example does, create and seed the files on-demand as you iterate over the string you're splitting.